# Need to start AGSI server with django rest framwork

Tags: django-rest-framework, websocket, django-channels

I am beginner with websocket and I need to make chat with Django channels. when i run the command to start ASGI server i got this error

> daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 project.asgi:application
> raise ImproperlyConfigured(
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

here is asgi.py

```
import os
import django
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from chat.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings


settings.configure(project.settings) 

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": URLRouter(
        websocket_urlpatterns
    ),
})
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles", 
    
    'djoser',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'channels',
    'channels_redis',
    
    
    # apps
    "accounts",
    "chat"
]
ASGI_APPLICATION = "project.asgi.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

I need to start web socket server to make api request for the chat app

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines at start of your asgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
```